# Query for false values in Access not working

Tags: microsoft-office, database, microsoft-access-2010, query

I'm trying to create a simple database to keep track of paperwork as it's turned in.  In the form and table I've used yes/no check boxes, checking them when a paper is turned in.

What I want to do is create a query so that I can get a list of which people are missing which paperwork.  When I try to set the criteria to false, I get nothing on from the query, but when I set it to True it just gives me a list of everyone that has turned everything in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the database structure, you will need to ensure that booleans (the data type behind the yes/no checkbox) are false by default.  It is possible that they are NULL by default (which means no value set).

Rather than querying on the criteria being **equal to false**, you could also try querying on the criteria being **not equal to true** - and that would cover the case of NULL as well.

In SQL, you would write that as:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourBooleanField <> True
```

Answer (score 0):

In databases, a "boolean" can have three values, not just two.  The values are True, False, and NULL.  NULL is a distinctly different value.  It is neither true nor false.  It is equal only to itself (not even 0), and is not greater than or less than any number.  It's only use is to test if a field actually *has* any data in it.

When you created your database, you did not give the field a default value, so the default value is NULL.